How to group by a key and collect other fields of json in that group in Groovy
I'm not a groovy-coder, but faced with it.
There is a json
[
  {
    "login": "nickname1",
    "status": "progress"
    "days": 8
  },
  {
    "login": "nickname2",
    "status": "progress",
    "days": 4
  },
  {
    "login": "nickname1",
    "status": "new",
    "days": 3
  },
  {
    "login": "nickname2",
    "status": "new",
    "days": 1
  }]

Need to get this:
[{
    "login": "nickname1",
"progress": 8,
"new": 3,
"total": 11
},
{
    "login": "nickname2",
"progress": 4,
"new": 1,
"total": 5
}]

Thank you!
I tried groupBy method, but couldn't understand, how to collect the "status"-fields.

You can use groupBy multiple times to get the result you require
def input = '''[
  {
    "login": "nickname1",
    "status": "progress",
    "days": 8
  },
  {
    "login": "nickname2",
    "status": "progress",
    "days": 4
  },
  {
    "login": "nickname1",
    "status": "new",
    "days": 3
  },
  {
    "login": "nickname2",
    "status": "new",
    "days": 1
  }
]'''

import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
import groovy.json.JsonBuilder

def modified = new JsonSlurper().parseText(input).groupBy { it.login }.collect {
    [login: it.key] + it.value.groupBy { it.status }.collectEntries { [it.key, it.value.days.sum()] }
}.collect {
    it + [total: it.findAll { it.key != 'login' }*.value.sum()]
}

def output = new JsonBuilder(modified).toPrettyString()

